# Angular $http.post method not working for asp.net web api

Tags: angularjs, ajax, asp.net-web-api, http-post

Gettting below error when trying $http.post from anugular js to asp.net web api

> angular.js:10722 OPTIONS
>   //localhost:54681/api/AccessToken/Generate (anonymous function) @
>   angular.js:10722sendReq @ angular.js:10515serverRequest @
>   angular.js:10222processQueue @ angular.js:14745(anonymous function) @
>   angular.js:14761$eval @ angular.js:15989$digest @
>   angular.js:15800$apply @ angular.js:16097(anonymous function) @
>   angular-touch.js:477dispatch @ jquery.js:4435elemData.handle @
>   jquery.js:4121 index.html#/access/signin:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>
> http://localhost:54681/api/AccessToken/Generate. Response for
>   preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404

My web api is running on //localhost:54681/ and my angular application running on //localhost:62319/

1 - Angular $http.post ajax method on //localhost:62319/

```
/// <reference path="../../../libs/angular/angular/angular.js" />
'use strict';

app.controller('SigninFormController', ['$scope', '$http', '$state', function ($scope, $http, $state) {
    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.authError = null;
    $scope.login = function () {
        debugger;
        $scope.authError = null;
        var data = { UserName: $scope.user.email, Password: $scope.user.password };

        $http.post('http://localhost:54681/api/AccessToken/Generate', data)
        .then(function (response) {
            debugger;
            //if (!response.data.user) {
            //    $scope.authError = 'Email or Password not right';
            //} else {
            //    $state.go('app.dashboard-v1');
            //}
        }, function (x) {
            debugger;
            console.log(x);
            //$scope.authError = 'Server Error';
        });
    };
}]);
```

2 - Asp.net Web Api controller on //localhost:54681/

```
[RoutePrefix("api/AccessToken")]
public class AccessTokenController : BaseApiController
{
    #region Properties And Variable Declaration

    private IAccessTokenCurator accessTokenCurator;

    #endregion Properties And Variable Declaration

    #region Constructor

    public AccessTokenController(IAccessTokenCurator accessTokenCurator)
    {
        this.accessTokenCurator = accessTokenCurator;
    }

    #endregion Constructor

    #region Access Token Operation

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Generate")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Generate(UserLogOn userLogOnModel)
    {
        ServiceResponse<string> serviceResponse = null;

        serviceResponse = new ServiceResponse<string>(await accessTokenCurator.Generate(userLogOnModel));

        return Request.CreateResponse<ServiceResponse<string>>(serviceResponse);
    }

    #endregion Access Token Operation
}
```

3 - UserLogOn class on //localhost:54681/

```
public class UserLogOn
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

4 - Web.config changes on //localhost:54681/

```
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="content-type" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Max-Age" value="1000" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Request-Method" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
```

Let me know where I am making mistake(s).

Comment: When i do this       $http.get('http://localhost:54681/api/AccessToken/Validate?token=xx4QQGImMLR9hG6Hbry%2FBvENEejJP5SOrAbtvJCgw2r%2F%2Fj0O01OuWgIbozkxKP0idF2Capx7Xtg%3D')
            .then(function (response) {
                debugger;
            }, function (x) {
                console.log(x);
                debugger;
        });

Then it works.
i.e. For Http Get request it is working but for Http Post it is not working.

Comment: One more thing $http.post works when i pass serilized data with form-urlencoded content-type header. But I am unable to pass json data using http.post method

Comment: the it seems it is how your server accepts the requests. Why not just specify that the data is form data?

Comment: Request Header 
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:27
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
DNT:1
Host:localhost:54681
Origin:http://localhost:62319
Referer:http://localhost:62319/src/index.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36

Comment: Response Header
Request URL:http://localhost:54681/api/AccessToken/Generate
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:[::1]:54681

when i pass serilized data with form-urlencoded content-type header then it works

Comment: what is response.body

Comment: Request URL:http://localhost:54681/api/AccessToken/Generate
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:404 Not Found
Remote Address:[::1]:54681




Cache-Control:private
Content-Length:5014
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Thu, 20 Oct 2016 13:33:58 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles:=?UTF-8?B?RDpcRGluZXNoXFNvdXJjZUNvZGVcSGVhbHRoIE1vbml0b3JcQmFzZVdlYkFwaVRlbXBsYXRlXFNlcnZpY2VzXEJhc2UuU2VydmljZXMuQXBpXGFwaVxBY2Nlc3NUb2tlblxHZW5lcmF0ZQ==?=

Comment: @joncodo It is making option request instead of post request.

---- Then it throws error : XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:54681/api/AccessToken/Generate. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:49241' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.
angularDOM.html:27 Object {data: null, status: -1, config: Object, statusText: ""}

Comment: So I'm guessing it makes the options request first to see if it can post. Then makes the post request. but the options one is blocked by cors. You need all routes true and your origin set on that request

Comment: @joncodo Yes!!! What setting has to be done on Web API side to allow option request so that it is not blocked by cors. ----------Can you explain in detail "You need all routes true and your origin set on that request "

Comment: $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'origin, content-type, accept';
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*';
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET,POST,PUT,HEAD,DELETE,OPTIONS';*/

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you are getting blocked by CORS [How does Access-Control-Allow-Origin header work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work)

Make sure to set:

```
'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' = 'origin, content-type, accept';
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' = '*';
'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' = 'GET,POST,PUT,HEAD,DELETE,OPTIONS';
```

**Step 1: Make sure your route actually works**

You can try a tool called [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/).

This will show you if your url route to /localhost:62319/ is working.

**Step 2: Test $http.post**

$http.post('http://localhost:54681/api/AccessToken/Generate?data=' + 'foo')

Does this method work for you?

**Step 3: Check the network tab and show the results**

Open up the chrome developer tools and find the network tab. Click on the request and then the response. Is it coming back as 404?

Comment: I use swagger for that thing and it works, actually when i do jquery ajax post then too it works but not for angular $htpp.post() method

Comment: try http.get('http://www.google.com') to make sure http is working for you in this page. Any console errors?

Comment: are you getting into the success or error function of the .post?